# Алгоритм для вычисления количества вариантов разбиения числа n на m слагаемых

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм, как посчитать, сколько существует вариантов разбить число n на m слагаемых, таким образом, чтобы каждое m i-тое не было больше какого-то k i-того?

пример: надо разбить число 5 на 3 слагаемых, первое слагаемое должно быть не больше 4, второе не больше 2, а третье не больше 4. В данном случае таких разбиений 5:

```
1 + 2 + 2 = 5
2 + 1 + 2 = 5
2 + 2 + 1 = 5
3 + 1 + 1 = 5
1 + 1 + 3 = 5
```

Comment: Да можно, например, рекурсивно, только с ограничением размера слагаемых и глубины рекурсии...

Comment: Ограничения какие? Проще всего рекурсивно посчитать, общей формулы для такого случая явно не существует.

Comment: @MBo ок, а как тогда рекурсивно посчитать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да можно, например, рекурсивно, только с ограничением размера слагаемых и глубины рекурсии...

Вот набросок на С++:

```
int f(int val, const vector<int>& c, int level = 0)
{
    if (val <= 0) return 0;
    if (level == c.size()) return 0;
    if (level == c.size()-1 && val <= c[c.size()-1]) return 1;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= c[level]; ++i) count += f(val-i,c,level+1);
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> c{4,2,4};
    cout << f(5,c);
}
```

Для больших значений желательна мемоизация, иначе долго считать будет...

Comment: Благодарствую вам!